# I updated java but java -version is still showing the old version on mac osx

Tags: java, macos

So I updated java to 1.7 but when I run java -version in terminal it still shows 1.6 as the version.

I updated by going to java.com and downloading the .dmg file and installing that.

Also eclipse still shows 1.6 as the version which I need 1.7.

How can I get java version 1.7 to show up everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely uninstall Java 1.6 and then reinstall 1.7 from scratch, rather than updating.